# Order by 2 values, using 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables

Sorry if this is a silly question, I searched a bit and couldn't find a solution for an example like mine.

I've got a small photo sharing app with a query which outputs the ID numbers of users, ordered by the number of followers they have. I want to alter the query slightly so that if users have the same number of followers, they will be ordered by the number of photos they've uploaded instead.

How would I go about editing my query? All attempts I've made have been unsuccessful.

Current query looks like this:

```
SELECT Users.ID, COUNT(User_Followers.FollowingUserID)
               AS follower_count FROM Users
               LEFT JOIN User_Followers ON Users.ID = User_Followers.FollowingUserID
               GROUP BY Users.ID
               ORDER BY follower_count DESC
```

Where the User_Followers table looks like this:

```
ID     UserID     FollowingUserID    DateFollowed
```

And the photos table looks like this:

```
ID     PostedByUserID     DatePosted
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  Users.ID,   
        COUNT(User_Followers.FollowingUserID) AS follower_count 
FROM    Users
        LEFT JOIN User_Followers 
            ON Users.ID = User_Followers.FollowingUserID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT PostedByUserID, COUNT(*) postCount
            FROM photos
            GROUP BY PostedByUserID
        ) a ON Users.ID = a.PostedByUserID
GROUP BY Users.ID
ORDER BY follower_count DESC, a.postCount DESC
```

Comment: Thanks very much! If I want to check the output (e.g in PHPMyAdmin) how would I modify this to display a third column showing the number of photos per user?

Comment: `SELECT  Users.ID,   
        COUNT(User_Followers.FollowingUserID) AS follower_count, a.postCount FROM....`

Comment: Thanks again, your help is much appreciated! As you may have guessed, MySQL isn't my specialty :P